# mysql: Group Concat with joined tables and values that aren't unique

Tags: mysql

I have an issue where I need to aggregate and concatenate multiple row data into single row output.  I understand the tables are a problem in that their is no unique index, but I need to do this at the query level instead of the scripting level and I can't touch the database structure.

Here we go:

table: characteristics

```
id          code_a       code_b
-------------------------------
2201         CHAU         AIRS
2201         CHAU         PELC
2201         PROX         AUTO
2201         PROX         HOP`
```

table: characteristics_types

```
code        description
-------------------------------
CHAU        Heating System
PROX        Nearby
```

table: characteristics_sub_types

```
code_a       code       description
-------------------------------
CHAU         AIRS         Forced Air
CHAU         PELC         Baseboard
PROX         AUTO         Highway
PROX         HOP          Hospital
```

Result required:

```
id      Heating System                 Nearby
--------------------------------------------------------
2201    Forced Air, Baseboard          Highway, Hospital
```

Not working:

```
SELECT id,
(case when C.code_a='CHAU' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(STC.description) ELSE NULL END) AS Heating System,
(case when C.code_a='PROX' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(STC.description) ELSE NULL END) AS Nearby

from characteristics C
        inner join characteristics_types TC on C.code_a=TC.`code`
        inner join characteristics_sub_types STC on C.code_a=STC.code_a and C.code_b=STC.`code`
            GROUP BY C.id,C.code_a
```

I am getting the following results:

```
id      Heating System                 Nearby
--------------------------------------------------------
2201    Forced Air, Baseboard         NULL
2201    NULL                          Highway, Hospital
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
SELECT c.id,
GROUP_CONCAT(STC.description_heating) AS `Heating System`,
GROUP_CONCAT(STC.description_nearby)  AS Nearby

from characteristics C
        inner join characteristics_types TC on C.code_a=TC.`code`
        inner join (
           SELECT code_a, code,
              CASE WHEN code_a = 'CHAU' THEN description ELSE null END as descriptio_heating,
              CASE WHEN code_a = 'PROX' THEN description ELSE null END as descriptio_nearby,
           FROM characteristics_sub_types 
        ) as STC on C.code_a=STC.code_a and C.code_b=STC.`code`
GROUP BY C.id
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response Alex!

However this is still returning multiple rows as what I had tried instead of a single row with the two column values

Comment: @Alex- fixed by removing the second group by, only grouping on the id.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT` accepts a `DISTINCT` keyword which is useful in *fan-out-queries*. You can also use `ORDER BY` within a `GROUP_CONCAT` if you need your results to be ordred. [See Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Using this, we can write your intended query like below:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ct.description) as 'Heating System',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cst.description) as 'Nearby'
FROM characteristics c 
  LEFT JOIN characteristics_types ct ON ct.id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN characteristics_sub_types cst 
    ON cst ON cst.code_a = c.code_a AND cst.code = c.code_b
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write separate subqueries, each one preforming the group_concat that you need, and join them together. Individually, I wrote them like this:

```
SELECT c.id, GROUP_CONCAT(cst.description) AS 'Heating System'
FROM characteristics c
JOIN characteristics_sub_types cst ON cst.code_a = c.code_a AND cst.code = c.code_b AND c.code_a = 'CHAU'
GROUP BY c.id;
```

And the join like this:

```
SELECT c.id, t1.`Heating System`, t2.`Nearby`
FROM(
  SELECT c.id, GROUP_CONCAT(cst.description) AS 'Heating System'
  FROM characteristics c
  JOIN characteristics_sub_types cst ON cst.code_a = c.code_a AND cst.code = c.code_b AND c.code_a = 'CHAU'
  GROUP BY c.id) t1
JOIN(
  SELECT c.id, GROUP_CONCAT(cst.description) AS 'Nearby'
  FROM characteristics c
  JOIN characteristics_sub_types cst ON cst.code_a = c.code_a AND cst.code = c.code_b AND c.code_a = 'PROX'
  GROUP BY c.id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Here is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e743/8).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id,
GROUP_CONCAT(STC.description_heating) AS `Heating System`,
GROUP_CONCAT(STC.description_nearby)  AS Nearby

from characteristics C
    inner join characteristics_types TC on C.code_a=TC.`code`
    inner join (
       SELECT code_a, code,
          CASE WHEN code_a = 'CHAU' THEN description ELSE null END as description_heating,
          CASE WHEN code_a = 'PROX' THEN description ELSE null END as description_nearby
       FROM characteristics_sub_types 
    ) as STC on C.code_a=STC.code_a and C.code_b=STC.`code`
GROUP BY C.id
```